# Firebase shows app version needs investigation

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

My app's firebase dashboard shows needs investigation (Analytics -> App release) I don't know why it is showing like that. Please see the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Searched google to find out the reason, but got no useful links. Anyone knows why it is showing "Needs investigation"?

Comment: I think you can better contact firebase support for this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Per https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7570091?hl=en

> Each release is given one of the following labels:
>
> Successful release: The release is stable ( < 1% crashing sessions) and adoption is greater than 10% of daily active users (DAU)*
>
> Needs investigation (yellow): 1% of sessions (100 crashes per 10k sessions) crashed today and yesterday
>
> Needs investigation (red): 10% of sessions (1k crashes per 10k sessions) crashed today and yesterday
>
> Previous release: The release’s first day with 10% of daily active users (DAU)* was earlier than 15 days ago
>
> Release in progress: Percentage of daily active users (DAU)* has increased by more than 2% since the first day of release
>
> Low adoption: Percentage of daily active users (DAU)* has not increased by more than 2% and has never reached 10% since the first day of release
>
> - This report calculates daily active users (DAU) for each app version for each day in the date range. Percentages are based on active users for all app versions.